# Source code to upload files from galley to server and display it in list in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone, hybrid-mobile-app

Shai Almog
You have made facebook clone and whatsapp clone.So you can easily help me.Can you please give me the source code for that or i have made a similar app in android studio and can I convert it to Codename one

Answer (score 2):

The full source code for these applications is available as part of this course https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java

Pulling out a snippet for something like this is nearly impossible as the apps are large and intertwined. There are samples for file upload in the javadocs and a sample image gallery in the kitchen sink demo.